# Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized error

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I was getting a :There is no row at position 0 previously.On debugging i noticed the Count of Table Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO is 0 .

Also when i placed breakpoint ,on some columns i am getting Cannot evaluate expression because the code of the current method is optimized error .
So what is going wrong here?

Here is the block of code where error is received :

```
 DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable HDT = new DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable();
DS_HOUSETableAdapters.HOUSE_SELECTTableAdapter HAdapter = new DS_HOUSETableAdapters.HOUSE_SELECTTableAdapter();
DS_USER.USERMST_SELECTDataTable UDT = new DS_USER.USERMST_SELECTDataTable();
DS_USERTableAdapters.USERMST_SELECTTableAdapter UAdapter = new DS_USERTableAdapters.USERMST_SELECTTableAdapter();

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
        lblsell.Text = "";
        UDT = UAdapter.Select_By_UID(Convert.ToInt32(Session["uid"].ToString()));
        HDT = HAdapter.Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO(UDT.Rows[0]["societyname"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(UDT.Rows[0]["HID"].ToString()));


            ViewState["HID"] = HDT.Rows[0]["HID"].ToString();
                        lblbno.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["blockno"].ToString();
            lbltype.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["type"].ToString();
            lblsname.Text = HDT.Rows[0]["sname"].ToString();
            Image3.ImageUrl = HDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString();
             }
```

Here is the defintion of Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO

```
         public virtual DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO(string sname, global::System.Nullable<int> bno) {
        this.Adapter.SelectCommand = this.CommandCollection[5];
        if ((sname == null)) {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[1].Value = ((string)(sname));
        }
        if ((bno.HasValue == true)) {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[2].Value = ((int)(bno.Value));
        }
        else {
            this.Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters[2].Value = global::System.DBNull.Value;
        }
        DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable dataTable = new DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable();
        this.Adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
```

Also stored procedure Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO code is :

```
create procedure Select_By_SNAME_BLOCKNO
@sname nvarchar(50),
@bno int
AS
BEGIN 
  select * from dbo.HouseMst where Sname=@sname and blockno=@bno
```

This returns the values but i am not able to retrieve on page.

Comment: I haven't test it, but seems the `SelectCommand.Parameters` is zero-based...

Comment: Make sure you compile you code using "Debug" configuration as opposed to "Release". You should be able to step through your code then.